# Converting radio button form output to JSON object for posting to Sheety/Google sheet

Tags: json, post

I've created a simple form using a radio button to get a Yes/No response from the user.  I'd like to post that response to a spreadsheet using Sheety.  I'm able to get data from the spreadsheet using fetch, but I'm not able to post the Yes/No response variable to the spreadsheet.  I'm pretty sure the problem is converting the Yes/No form response variable to a JSON object.  The relevant code is shown below.  The line commented out (question1: "no") is the key:value pair that needs to be sent to the spreadsheet.  If I remove the "//" I can send that data.  The problem is I want that to be a variable depending on what's been selected in the form.  I don't know how to convert the form data into a JSON object and insert it into the "body" variable.  Maybe someone can point to a fix???  Thanks in advance for any help/guidance provided.

```
    let url = 'https://api.sheety.co/<Sheety ID>/surveyTest/sheet1';
    let body = {
        sheet1: {
        //question1: "no"   (I want this to be the variable from the form data input)
        }
    }
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        // Do something with object
        console.log(body);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my own question.  If I was a more-experience coder I would have figured this out sooner.  All I had to do is create a new object variable with the correct format for the POST to Sheety.  It looks like this:

```
var formObject =  {"sheet1": 
    {"question1": selectedValue 
    }};
```

The selectedValue is from the form.